# How to numbering a set of paper

Tags: software-recommendation, book, batch-processing

I have 500 page I want to restore it digitally, they are a set of pages from a very old book I already have and want to reprint it again with my digital restoration. all the pages have no page numbers.

After scanning all the pages, I was wondering if there is any way to renumber those pages without open the 500 page in Photoshop and type the page number!?

I am asking of a batch, a software (or a smart way) that could render numbers in a certain position to all my 500 page, just like the way we watermark photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your scans are consistent (same size and positioning), you could simply create an InDesign document, import them in and use the Masters to place your pagination number. It'll then apply to all the pages and you'll be able to export a PDF.

For quicker placing of your images, I'm fairly sure something could be programmed to do this in InDesign using the scripting features (Javascript or Applescript) but I'm not knowledgeable enough in this field to guide you more.

Comment: +1 It seems like a good solution, you have just inspire me by putting a 500 page together using the datamerge feature in Indesign using [this script](http://indesignsecrets.com/downloads/forcedl/imagesToCSV104.jsx) after adjusting my masterpage with page numbering :) brilliant .. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a script I have just found doing the job quite well, specially when I include it in an action for re-positioning.

the script is `Add File Name as Text Layer` and you can find it [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2010/09/add-file-name-as-text-layer.html)

simply the script add a text layer that contains the name of the opened file. so what i have to do is to rename all files to have the exact numbering order and let the my action do the job.